# More space below the section title

Tags: spacing, color, titlesec

I'm having some troubles to add space in my section title. Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\usepackage{titlesec}
       \titleformat{\section}[block]
       {\centering\Large}
       {}
       {0cm}
       {\colorsection}
      
      \newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
        \colorbox{bleudefrance!80!black}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering\color{white}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}

\section{Conservation of Lineal Momentum}
[text]
```

The question is the next: How can I add space below the section title? I dont want space between title-text, I want to make bigger the color area (idk how to say it).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `\strut` directive to the 2nd set of arguments of `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\centering\Large}{}{0cm}{\colorsection}
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{bleudefrance!80!black}{\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}%
      {\centering\color{white}\strut\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Conservation of Lineal Momentum}
[text]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks!

Comment: @Peluche - I'm blushing... Incidentally, if `\strut` enlarges the title area a bit too much for your taste, you could replace it with `$\mathstrut$`.